# implement hls.js library with vuejs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I need some help trying to figure out how to use the [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) library in vuejs as it has no specific documentation of how to implement it with vue. The situation here is that I have to fetch the m3u8 from an api I'm able to make it work from a basic html with the  tag and cdn but when I try to implement it with vuejs it doesn't work, any help is appreciated. I've tried 2 implementations and got the same error each time. These are what I've got so far:

**First try**: use cdn and include in it component

```
export default {
  head() {
     return {
       script: [
         {
           src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest'
         }
       ],
     }
   }}
```

with function in created()

```
    checkHLS(){
      console.log('in');
      if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        console.log('working')
      }
    },
```

**Second Try** install the package using npm

```
npm install --save hls.js
```

and i got this error

```
                                  Hls is not defined
An error occurred while rendering the page. Check developer tools console for details.
```

Answer (score 6):

Install hls.js via npm:
`npm i --save hls.js@latest`

Here is how you can use it in a component:

```
<template>
  <video ref="video" width="100%" height="640" controls></video>
</template>

<script>
import Hls from 'hls.js';

export default {
  mounted() {
    let hls = new Hls();
    let stream = "http://demo.unified-streaming.com/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8";
    let video = this.$refs["video"];
    hls.loadSource(stream);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
      video.play();
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: hey @7hny "this" is not available here in the hls.on event listener, correct? how could I inject hls.js so that I could use it like $hls?

Comment: Use arrow function: `hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => { video.play(); });`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752158/nuxt-plugin-cannot-access-vues-this-instance-in-function-blocks I managed it like this thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try npm module for working with m3u8 video. This package works with vue3

[vue-hls-video-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hls-video-player)

Probably, this module could solve your problem

```
  npm i vue-hls-video-player

  <VideoPlayer
    type="default"
    @pause="processPause"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    :progress="30"
    class="customClassName"
  />

  <VideoPlayer
    type="preview"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    class="customClassName"
  />
```