# Nuxt plugin cannot access Vue's 'this' instance in function blocks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, hls.js, nuxtjs2

So I have managed to inject hls.js to work with nuxtjs $root element and `this`

I did so doing it like this (hls.client.js):

```
import Hls from 'hls.js';

export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('myhls', Hls)
}
```

and nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
  '~plugins/hls.client.js',
],
```

This works great, literally :-) but I can't reference 'this' in the hls events.

```
playHls() {
      this.playing = true
      if(this.$myhls.isSupported()) {
        this.hls = new this.$myhls();
        this.audio = new Audio('');
        this.hls.attachMedia(this.audio);
        this.hls.loadSource(this.scr_arr[2]);
        this.audio.play()
        // 'THIS' DOES NOT WORK INSIDE this.hls.on
        this.hls.on(this.$myhls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
          console.log(this.scr_arr[2]); // DOES NOT LOG
          console.log("ok")  // works great                  
        });
        // 'THIS' DOES NOT WORK INSIDE this.hls.on 
        this.hls.on(this.$myhls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
          console.log('manifest loaded, found ' + data.levels.length + ' quality level') // WORKS
          console.log("ok") // WORKS
          this.audio.volume = 1   // DOES not work   
        });
      }
    },
```

So I in these Events I can't use nuxtjs 'this', cause there seems to be a different scope?

Can I somehow get 'this' nuxt scope inside these Events?

Comment: Isn't `this.hls.attachMedia` supposed to be `this.$myhls.attachMedia`?

Comment: Also, if you want to use `this.audio.volume`, use an arrow function `() =>` rather than `function (event, data) {`.

Comment: @kissu this.$myhls is just the Hls object. It has the public method isSupported().

I tried to inject new Hls() instead but this does not expose isSupported() at all.

Comment: @kissu about the usage of this.audio.volume your method works, great. Is it because of then it is not a callback function?

Comment: See there is a difference between getting the normal constructor and the Hls Object:

`if(this.$myhls.isSupported()) {   // Hls.isSupported()`
`this.hls = new this.$myhls();  // <= new Hls()`

I only injected 'Hls' not 'new Hls()'

Comment: In a block scope (`function() {` syntax), `this` is bind to the nested scope and not vue's `this` instance. If you want to keep `this` inside of a function, use an arrow function (ES6) or you can have `const that = this` and use `that` in a regular `function()  {` if you prefer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @kissu that was the issue :-) ah these pitfalls sometimes :-) Thanks a bunch, once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your functions like

```js
this.hls.on(this.$myhls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
```

into

```js
this.hls.on(this.$myhls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, (event, data) => {
```

to keep the `this` context tied to the Vue app, otherwise it will be scoped to the context of the block scope.